# Is this allowed syntax for defaulted template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to be able to have a template type argument as empty, which case the class just has an empty T, or U, or whatever. I tried to do this defaulting the template argument to a simple lambda:

```
template <typename U = decltype([]() {})>
```

On Visual Studio 2019 16.9.3 I don't get the right result when I query the type of U, but by trying to compile on OnlineGDB I found out that this probably shouldn't be compiling anyway because the defaulted argument is defining a new type:

```
    #include <iostream>
    template <typename T, typename U = decltype([]() { }) >
    struct Planet
    {
        T T_obj;
        [[no_unique_address]] U U_obj;
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        Planet<int, char> planet;
    
        std::cout << "Typename = " << typeid([]() {}).name() << '\n'; // Type here is a lambda, which is correct
        std::cout << "Typename of U = " << typeid(planet.U_obj).name() << '\n'; // Type here is int, why?
        std::cout << "Typename of U = " << typeid(Planet<int>::U_obj).name() << '\n'; // Type here is int, why?
    }
```

Is this just some sort of bug? If I cannot do 'decltype([] () {})' then I can just define 'struct EmptyType{};' just above the template without a problem.

Comment: On [this list - c++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) you can find *Lambdas in unevaluated contexts*. Your compiler supports it (MSVC since 16.8), but IMHO it gives wrong results. [Live demo for G++](https://godbolt.org/z/Kbe7rvEja) works better for me. In first case it returns `char`, in second lambda.

Comment: I think Brian Bi's answer answers your question but just a remark on alternatives: Instead of defining a `struct EmptyType` you could also make `T_obj` and `U_obj` plain or even better smart pointers and default `U` to `void`. In case T and U share a common base you could also make a variadic template which forwards them to a polymorphic vector of smart pointers to the base class which might be handy in case you need more than two template parameters for your application at some point.

Comment: @2b-t I don't understand what you mean, but I'm interested, could you show me with a link maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++17, a lambda may not appear in an unevaluated context. This restriction was lifted in C++20, but your compiler might not have implemented this feature yet (even if it already supports `[[no_unique_address]]`, another C++20 feature), so you need to upgrade your compiler. And in any case I would recommend not writing code like this, because it would mean that `Planet<int>` would not be the same type as `Planet<int>` (even within the same TU), as a new lambda type will be created every time the default argument is used. `void` might work better as the default type, and you can give `U_obj` some private empty class type in the case where `U` is `void`.

Answer (score 1):

The **correct answer** to the question was given by **Brian Bi** (see above). This post is just a follow-up that started from a comment discussion and was requested by the original poster to be elaborated in more detail and might be helpful to somebody trying achieve the same behaviour. Therefore I decided to post it over here rather than somewhere hidden in the comment. The solutions are not equivalent (e.g. stack vs heap allocation) and partially also have a different interface.

---

**Dummy struct**

One possible solution would be to simply pass a dummy struct as a default parameter as follows ([Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nR5GF6Lt1bmxGslH))

```
struct DummyStruct {
};
template <typename T, typename U = DummyStruct>
struct Planet {
    Planet(T const t, U const u = {})
    : t_{t}, u_{u} {
        return;
    }
    T t_;
    U u_;
};
```

---

**Pointer to void**

Similarly one could use plain or smart pointers and a default type `void`. The given constructor will not work with template deduction but you can always write a constructor with smart pointers ([Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X1tLKtEStxqarU2h)).

```
template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct Planet {
    // Trick to disable this constructor for type void in order to avoid compilation error
    template<typename T1 = T, typename U1 = U,
             typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<U1,void> && std::is_same_v<U1,U>>* = nullptr>
    Planet(T1 const& t, U1 const& u)
    : t_{std::make_shared<T>(t)}, u_{std::make_shared<U>(u)} {
        return;
    }
    Planet(T const& t)
    : t_{std::make_shared<T>(t)}, u_{nullptr} {
        return;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> t_;
    std::shared_ptr<U> u_;
};
```

---

**Variadic templates and tuples**

One might as well use variadic templates in combination with tuples and then access them with std::get(...) but the usage might be a bit inconvenient ([Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sSAdZ9SsBKaNRyrg))

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Planet {
    Planet(Ts const&... t)
    : t_{std::make_tuple(t...)} {
        return;
    }
    std::tuple<Ts...> t_;
};
```

---

**Polymorphic vector**

Another possibility in some special cases where the involved containers are derived from a common base class and therefore share a common interface is using a `std::vector` of smart pointers such as ([Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mR7qlha7FaxkqLot)):

```
struct Parent {
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

struct Child: public Parent {
    void update() override {
        // Do something
        return;
    }
};

struct Planet {
    template <typename... Ts>
    Planet(std::shared_ptr<Ts>&... t)
    : t_{t...} {
        // Static assertion with fold expression
        static_assert((std::is_base_of_v<Parent, Ts> && ...), "Template arguments must inherit from 'Parent'.");
        return;
    }
    
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Parent>> t_;
};
```

Comment: Most of these aren't equivalent suggestions to the original code in the question. The `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute helps to pack the different `struct` objects and allows all state to be local in the same class -- but any suggestions with `vector`, `shared_ptr`, etc is using a extra data both on the heap and elsewhere. It's not _wrong_ exactly, but it's certainly not equivalent either.

Comment: @Human-Compiler You are certainly right: they are not equivalent to the original code but they might be helpful nonetheless. I just could not fit all that into a comment and I think it might be useful for somebody stumbling across this post.